# What are the disadvantages of $http.useApplyAsync?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently exploring $http in angularjs, and I've seen this super-amazing method: `useApplyAsync` which will synchronize my $http requests, and will make my app faster.

All good, but why by default angularjs is setting it to false? Are there any disadvantages of using it?

## EDIT:

I also made a comparison between using `useApplyAsync` and not using it.

Here I used it: http://jsfiddle.net/vwnLz344/17/
Here I didn't use it: http://jsfiddle.net/vwnLz344/18/

I am unable to see the advantages of it...

What I am searching for is: The Advantages and the Disadvantages  of: `useApplyAsync`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably doesn't make a huge difference with a smaller app - by the sounds of things `useApplyAsync` will delay processing by ~10ms but aggregates processing of responses so may be slightly faster if say multiple responses come in within that window it might allow them to share a digest cycle avoiding extra overheads.

The default behavior processes each individual response more quickly (I think synchronously) but might require more digest cycles if multiple responses are received in quick succession which might require more processing and hence be slower overall.

So short answer `useApplyAsync` is probably faster with many rapid requests that update a lot of data, the default behavior is probably faster with less frequent requests.

I'd guess that it's disabled by default as usually if you're firing off that many AJAX requests you probably need to rethink your API (ie provide options for consolidating the requests).

**Advantages of enabling useApplyAsync**

If multiple responses are received in short succession it might reduce the amount of digest cycles required

**Disadvantages of enabling useApplyAsync**

It may delay processing of a response by ~10ms whilst waiting to aggregate processing

**Why is it disabled by default?**

Delaying processing of most AJAX requests by ~10ms for a short window to attempt to process multiple responses concurrently and avoid additional digest cycles is for most use cases less desirable than the few additional digest cycles it might  save by enabling it.

**The relevant docs have more info**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#useApplyAsync

> **useApplyAsync([value]);**
>
> "Configure $http service to combine processing of multiple http
> responses received at around the same time via $rootScope.$applyAsync.
> This can result in significant performance improvement for bigger
> applications that make many HTTP requests concurrently (common during
> application bootstrap).
> "

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync

> **$applyAsync([exp]);**
>
> Schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a later time. The actual
> time difference varies across browsers, but is typically around ~10
> milliseconds.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

> **$apply([exp]);**
>
> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

Comment: if I have a small app, than `useApplyAssync` will not affect my API, so why it's just not enabled by default? I still don't understand the disadvantage of it.

Comment: @PHPLover That's because you love PHP? Jokes aside, the reason why it's turned off by default is because that's how the web works currently. You can't force a developer into something different just because you yourself can't see a disadvantage in using it for your specific application. Languages and features aren't written specifically for you, so take "you" out of the equation and step into a developer who might need it to act synchronously (which is most of them, hence the default setting to false)

Comment: The disadvantage is it might delay processing of the response for ~10ms whilst waiting to aggregate the requests, so say you receive one response every ~100ms you might delay each responses processing by 10ms waiting to aggregate processing of other requests. If a little extra latency on processing of the request is less important than minimizing digest cycles enable it, if latency is critical and minimizing digest cycles is less important then leave it on default would be my recommendation. I think it's disabled by default as ~10ms extra latency on most requests < the few digest cycles saved

Comment: @zerohero I feel this is more a performance tuning option - either behavior to the dev will "feel" the same ie it won't impact how most apps are written. But the default behavior for your typical use case should save on latency as aggregation is unlikely to occur often. The likely exception as mentioned in the docs is when bootstrapping the app. However IMO if you're sending that many requests then probably should either aggregate them, use Web Sockets, either that or manually handling aggregation, and considering compiling your templates.

Comment: @Brian I agree, but lets say I have 3 ajax requests and one promise needs to be fulfilled before the other 2 can run. I would not want that to be async by default, but choose to enable when the situation calls for it. If you have to resort to aggregating these ajax calls in your application, like you mentioned, you need to relook at your application and not necessarily optimize to that degree.

Comment: @zerohero yeah that's fair enough, it's all about using the right tool for the job. I probably should have clarified better for 2-3 requests it may not be worth aggregating (or leveraging the other options I suggested), I only see this option being of value if making quite a few concurrent requests  (I mean like 20+ in rapid succession) or possibly if you have a very expensive digest cycle as well as potentially closely spaced responses.